# Setting default url in axios

Tags: node.js, axios

I am using axios in my Node project and experiencing unexpected difficulties with apparently basic task of setting the defaults.

What is the correct way?
Should I use axios.create() at all or not?

I used 2 ways of configuring axios:

1.

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = baseURL;
axios.defaults.headers = headers;
```

2.

```
axios.create({ baseURL, headers });
```

In both cases I see that when I make request, the final URL is not correct in all environments.

Does anyone have idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you setting your baseURL to?

Comment: Basically HOST + ":" + PORT +"/" + "PREFIX"

e.g. http://localhost:80/v1

Comment: The way I have it set up is: `Axios.defaults.baseURL = window.location.origin + "/api/";`

Comment: Instead of `/api/` you could do `/v1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use `axios.create`, for example if your app requests an api, do this :

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api',
    headers: {
        'Api-Key': 'XXXXXXXXX'
    }
});
```

So you can use it like `api.get('/ping');`

Comment: This is exactly what did not work for me. It kind of ignores baseUrl.

Comment: Are you sure you're using 'api.get' instead of 'axios.get' ? Can you show me your code ?

Comment: @YehvegHD, you are right, I was actually using directly axios.get().

I would like to avoid using the AxiosInstance. Is it still possible to use it correctly directly?

Comment: If axios.defaults doesn’t work I think it’s not possible :/ (don’t forget to mark my answer as correct if I helped )